# Query any 2 random contacts

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I need to query any 2 random contacts related to account and I want those to be displayed on VF Page using pageBlockTable. Can someone help me build the query for the requirement...

I've tried the below query but it's throwing an error and I am not sure how to troubleshoot it...

```
conList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 2) FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accList];
```

Comment: It'd help if you included the error message (in its entirety, don't try to paraphrase it). Add it to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: Please do not delete and repost closed questions. If your question is closed, you need to _improve_ it by making an [edit]. You can learn more about our expectations and format at [ask] and [help/on-topic].

Comment: I'm getting the following error message while running the query.
**Illegal assignment from List<Account> to List<Contact>**

I tried giving Schema.ObjectName but that doesn't work. Help me solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The query is wrong. While using a nested query you should use relationship name.
Try the following:

```
conList = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Contacts LIMIT 2) FROM Account WHERE Id IN:accList];
```

[Nested Query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm)

Comment: I'm getting the following error message while running the query. 
**Illegal assignment from List<Account> to List<Contact>**
I tried giving Schema.ObjectName but that doesn't work. Help me solve this.

Comment: As the error signifies you need to store the above query in List<Account>, not in List<Contact>. The primary query is of the Account object and not the Contact object.
I suggest you first complete the following trailmix:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/force_com_dev_beginner